# Accessing various elements in an array in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, taffydb

I am building an application using Angular js and Taffy DB.

javascript:

```
$scope.viewTable=function () {
  $scope.resultlists=[];
  $scope.resultSet=teamlist().get();
  var teamdata=$scope.resultSet;
  angular.forEach(teamdata,function(teamdata,i){
    if (i<length) {
    console.log(teamdata[i].text);
    }
  });
};
```

I have an array result from Taffy DB like this.
teamdata contains

```
[Object { text="zxcxzc", $$hashKey="00A", ___id="T000002R000002", more...}, Object { text="czxcz", $$hashKey="00C", ___id="T000002R000003", more...}, "zxczxc", Object { undefined={...}, ___id="T000002R000005", ___s=true}, 5454575, Object { undefined={...}, ___id="T000002R000007", ___s=true}, 2, 2727287.5]
```

and I have to display each element in a table.

How to access each element in the above array?

Please Advice

Comment: you are using the `teamdata` variable again in the forEach funcion scope, then the reference inside that method is not your aray anymore, but your new variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the angular.forEach for arrays is as follows:

```
angular.forEach(array, function(element) { ... })
```

So you should be able to access each row like that:

```
angular.forEach(teamdata, function(row) {

  // ... row.text
});
```

[angular.forEach documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach)

Comment: it works.I need to seperate like as follows:                                                               1.Object { text="zxcxzc", $$hashKey="00A", ___id="T000002R000002", more...}, Object { text="czxcz", $$hashKey="00C", ___id="T000002R000003", more...}                                                             2."zxczxc"                                                           3. Object { undefined={...}, ___id="T000002R000005", ___s=true}, 5454575, Object { undefined={...}, ___id="T000002R000007", ___s=true}                                                            4.2 and so on

Comment: can u please suggest?